# Checking Image Size Jquery

Tags: jquery

just messing about trying to learn it. Im trying to validate an image from an upload. Checking the image type works fine with the code below. but im trying to check  its size. Can anyone explain why this is not working please.

Thanks.

```
  $('#File').change(function (evt) {
            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();


            var H = f.height;
            var W = f.width;

            if (W > 100) {
                alert("The selected file is too large.");
                return;
            }


            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                alert("The selected file does not appear to be an image.");
                return;
            }

            setBox('#IsFile');
            reader.onload = function (e) { preview.attr('src', e.target.result); };
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });
```

Comment: It's not working because the API provides no support for it. The "height" and "width" properties will always be `undefined`, in other words. (At least, that's true in my browser.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. So is it not possible to check the image size in jquery?

Comment: Well you could do it, but you'd have to read the file contents and then decode the image format enough to extract that information with your own code.

Comment: I suppose you could load it into a hidden element and do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: Yes, that would be a lot easier than my dumb idea :)

Comment: @Robb not hidden...offscreen though will work

Comment: @charlietfl err right. Hidden wouldn't work would it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to load the image into an offscreen image element and then detect the Width/Height using a method similar to this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('offscreenImageId'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```